# Long filename causes crash after compilation

Tags: miktex, windows

`xxxxxxxxxxxx.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

LaTeX/MiKTeX compiles the file just fine, but it crashes at the end:

[image: Screenshot of crash]

When I shorten the file name, then the problem goes away.

*Is there a fix, or is it generally not possible for LaTeX/MiKTeX to work with filenames greater than 11.3?*

Version:

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5670 (1.40.16) (MiKTeX 2.9)
```

OS: Windows 7 X64

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the very same setup.

Comment: For me it compiles perfectly too with the exact same setup...

Comment: The error message doesn't seem related to the main file name, but rather to a malformed entry in the FNDB database. Try rebuilding it from the MiKTeX wizard.

Comment: @egreg Rebuild the FNDB database from the MikTeX Settings dialog I did, already before posting the question. It didn't help.

Comment: The same problem with Miktex x64 on our site on several Win7x64 machines with third party Editors like WinEdt or TexnicCenter.
The Miktex x32 version with the same updatelevel works fine.
uj